# createImageBitmap with resize: doesn't work on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas

Looking at the MDN page for [createImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) it states that Chrome supports the options parameter from 52 onwards. But in testing with Chrome 57, I can't seem to get the `resizeWidth` or `resizeHeight` options to work. I've got a demo running here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVwrXN

From my understanding, what I've provided should end up with an image bitmap half the size of the original image being drawn to the canvas tag, but it appears to be full size (I know I can rescale in `drawImage()` but that's not what I'm looking for here). I found some [Chromium notes](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-reviews/d6jos7-Mx_g) on implementing it that makes it sound like it should work, so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today, (on both chrome 60 canary and stable 57) you still need to set the *Experimental canvas features*  flag in `chrome://flags`.

I agree that MDN page should state this.

---

*Edit 2021:*
Chrome now supports this natively. But other browsers still don't (Safari doesn't support the API at all). If you need this for cross-browsers projects, I wrote a [createImageBitmap monkey-patch](https://github.com/Kaiido/createImageBitmap) which enables this feature in all browsers.

Comment: Hi, I enabled "Accelerated 2D canvas", "Enable pixel canvas recording", "Display Autofill Dropdown Using Views", this is all the features corresponding to search "canvas". When I look in https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVwrXN?editors=1111, the second image is still the same size than the 1st one, where it s supposed to be the half.
My Chrome version is: Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Did I miss something?

Comment: @CedricArnould they did move experimetal canvas features into experimental web features. I should update the answer, thanks for the head up.